# Bim360: API to create checklist from template

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In our project we need a way to programmatically create a bunch of checklists based on a template.

According to the [Bim360 checklists API documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/checklists-instances-GET/) there are methods to *read* checklists data. AFAIK, in 'legacy' API there were methods to create/update/delete checklists.

Question for the Autodesk team: Are there any plans to add support for these methods in Bim360 API?

Comment: I hate to disappoint you, it is true the API to update checklists or create checklist has not been exposed. We have  wish (ID=BIMAPI-91). Please send us with your email address, company,short description requirements background at forge.help@autodesk.com. I will append it to the wish for engineer team to evaluate. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thanks for reply! I've just sent an email